# php with nginx gets message "No input file specified."

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I am running a web server on a modified router, and I am having issues with PHP.  I keep getting the message:

> No input file specified.

I have searched and read a lot of the messages posted about this issue, but have not been able to resolve the issue.  I am using NGINX as the web server, and if I use the built in PHP, it works no problem, but when I try to use the PHP installed from opkg, I get that message.  The reason I want to use the PHP installed from opkg is that it is more updated and it includes mysqli, which the other one doesn't.  Can someone please help?

Comment: How did you modify the router?  What kind of router it is?  What OS it is running?  How did you install PHP on it?  What did you read about it?  I can keep going and going... but  believe that makes the point already: you need to give as much background as possible, no one knows what goes in your head.

Comment: I have installed a hobby tomato on an  Asus router. The tomato version is
tomato-RT-AC56U-ARM--132-AIO-64K and it comes with PHP version 5.5. I installed PHP version 5.6 using entware opkg.  I have verified that NGINX is configured correctly because it works when I run the original PHP. I am running PHP with the command php-cgi -b 127.0.01:9001.

Comment: I think I figured it out.  In the PHP.ini file was the line `doc_root = "/opt/share/www/`.  Once I removed this line it seems to work.

Comment: Cool.  I also checked that tomato is a unix flavour and you might therefore get better answers on the [U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) part of the website.  On more thing, you should always edit your question not just keep adding info in comments.